# Could I move several files with terminal command "mv" on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, mv

I have this problem when I try to move several files. I have 3 files that I need to move without putting on a subfolder.

These files have long names, which makes the task more difficult.

Example:

```
Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_81--102).pdf
Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_103--122).pdf
Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_123--155).pdf
```

How to solve this problem in terminal?

I'll be very grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by "need move without put on a subfolder"? Could you edit your question to show the expected result of the move operation, and also what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just trying to simplify the entry of long file names on the command lines, in bash you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> key to simplify the entry. e.g. enter the start of a command, e.g. `mv L` and then hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key, and it will automatically autocomplete up to the point that the names are ambiguous (e.g. up to the page numbers). Autocomplete makes entering these names really easy.

If you’re looking to rename a bunch of files, a common trick is to

- use `ls` to get list of relevant files and use `sed` to build script for renaming these files, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ls L* | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)--\([0-9]*\)).pdf/mv "&" Pages\1-\2.pdf/'
  ```

  That looks for a string of characters that aren’t digits, then grabs the digits before and after the `--` and then outputs a string `mv` followed by original name followed by new name that incorporates the page numbers. I know it’s a bit hairy, but it’s the power of regular expressions. And this doesn’t actually do the renaming yet, but rather creates commands that can do the renaming should you choose to do so.

  Anyway, that produces text output like:

  ```
  mv "Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_103--122).pdf" Pages103-122.pdf
  mv "Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_123--155).pdf" Pages123-155.pdf
  mv "Lógica_matemática_para_ingeniería_de_sistemas_y_co..._----_(Pg_81--102).pdf" Pages81-102.pdf
  ```

  You can google `sed` tutorials/examples if you want to figure out the rich array of alternatives available. And, if it gets really complicated, there are alternatives including `awk` and/or shell scripts.
- Anyway, once you visually inspect it and decide those generated `mv` commands look good, you can repeat the process, this time piping the output to `sh` to actually perform the renaming:

  ```
  $ ls L* | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)--\([0-9]*\)).pdf/mv "&" Pages\1-\2.pdf/' | sh
  ```

There are other file renaming utilities that you can install, but old-school Unix folk will generally get `sed` do the process for us.

Comment: Thanks your answer it's great.

**sed** it's very strong.